# Can't send mail via php with msmtp

Tags: postfix, php-fpm, sendmail, msmtp

I want the server able to send mail via gmail smtp.
The installation of msmtp was successful. I able to send using msmtp via the command line. However, when I try to send via php, it got me this error.

> postfix/smtp[11241]: connect to
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.27]:25: Connection timed out
>
> postfix/smtp[11241]: connect to
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1b]:25: Network is
>   unreachable connect to
>   alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
>
> postfix/smtp[11241]: 8F4DB10D10: to=, relay=none,
>   delay=1086, delays=993/0.13/93/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect
>   to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed
>   out)

I had change the postfix config file

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

to

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

But still no avail

Any idea why?

By the way, I am using Centos with LEMP stack.

Comment: Who is your service provider?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, turn out is the msmtp config file permission issue. I change it to the proper user and group, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending email from gmail, meaning your gmail account & clearly using postfix you'll need sasl auth and use Google's smtp connection on port 587... [Postfix-Gmail guide](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/)